# Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to run a junit test from within eclipse and I am getting the "Failed to load ApplicationContext" exception. The reason is that its trying to load a spring-config which uses a variable defined in another spring-config. For ex:

common-beans.xml uses ${domain} and ${realm} 
and these are defined in config2.xml as:

```
<bean id="AppConfigHelper" class="AppConfigHelper">
    <property name="appName" value="Service"/>
    <property name="domain" value="unittest"/>
    <property name="realm" value="asdf"/>
    <property name="root" value="./build/private/unittestroot"/>
</bean>
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'bucketPartitionMapper' defined in URL [file:spring-configuration/common/common-beans.xml]: ***Could not resolve placeholder 'domain'***

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, Spring is not able to resolve the 'domain' placeholder.  That means, in common-beans.xml, you are utilizing ${domain}, but Spring can not find out the value for that placeholder.  The code that you pasted only sets the domain attribute for AppConfigHelper's domain attribute, it does *not* set the placeholder.

In order to set the placeholder, create a file called application.properties and have it contain the following:

> domain=YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE

Then you need to set up a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your application, like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here are some resources to help you out:
[PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and [an example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/)